# Use a default imgUrl string in case there's no valid image u

Tags: html, css

I would like this alt to be used when there's no valid imageUrl found in the database, in case someone didn't add a imageUrl. Couldn't find a solution in other threads.

```
          <img class="card-img-top" src={{p.imageurl}} alt="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/construction-glyphs-2/128/57-512.png">
```

Comment: Seems like the most straight forward solution would be to set it up with an if statement `if(imageurl=='') {imageurl = 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/construction-glyphs-2/128/57-512.png'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do it like this:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src={{p.imageurl}} onerror="this.src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/construction-glyphs-2/128/57-512.png'">
```